# Como fazer o posicionamento dinâmico JsPDF

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jspdf

Estou utilizando o plugin *jsPDF* para gerar um PDF. No meu método criado, recebo um array, percorro ele, tento escrever e posicionar dinamicamente no PDF, porém estou sem ideia de como fazer isso.

```
 $scope.gerarPdf = function (item) {
        var doc = new jsPDF();

        for (var i = 0; i < item.length; i++) {
            doc.text(item[i].nome, x, y);
            doc.text(item[i].validade,  x, y);
            doc.text(item[i].saldoParcial,  x, y);
        }
        doc.save('teste.pdf');
        return doc;
    };
```

Onde possuí: 'x', 'y', é onde queria definir o posicionamento de forma dinâmica.

Comment: Eu fiz isso em um projeto um tempo atras, eu pego o valor inicial e vou incrementando de acordo com a quantidade de registros

Comment: Tentei fazer isso utilizando o 'i' da interação, mas saiu desalinhado..

Comment: Está no caminho certo, agora é só questão de calcular certo

Answer (score 1):

Você está no caminho certo, é só questão de cálculo. Olha esse exemplo:

```
var x = 15;
var y = 20;

for (var i = 0; i < item.length; i++) {
    doc.text(item[i].nome, x, y);
    doc.text(item[i].validade,  x, y+6);
    doc.text(item[i].saldoParcial,  x, y+12);
    y = y + 20
}
```

Fazendo isso já iria ser colocado todos os dados um a baixo do outro na mesma coluna. Para mudar de coluna, basta editar o X também.